# How do I crop from the default image viewer?

Tags: 11.10, image-processing, image-viewers

I recall an **Edit Image** button in 11.04 that would bring up a second window with a **Crop** button easily visible.

But now, in 11.10, I see no such button.  In fact, I can't find a way to crop at all from the default image viewer.

How can I crop an image from the default image viewer?

Comment: It looks like Eye Of GNOME (the default Image viewer) doesn't have a 'crop' function built in, nor is there a plugin in eog-plugins, however it is listed as an "Idea" on the project page: http://live.gnome.org/EyeOfGnome/Plugins

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Once the image is opened you can right click on it and choose to open with *Shotwell Image Viewer*. It will open up a new window where you can crop/edit the image and save it.
Once saved you can close the 2nd window and see the changes in the default image viewer.

Alternatively you can set *Shotwell Image Viewer* to be your default image viewer.

Comment: I am reasonably sure that this is what you are thinking of. Somewhere along the line, they experimented with using this instead of EOG; I think it made it into a release or two.

Comment: There might even be an edit button in EOG (the default viewer) that will open it in the Shotwell Image Viewer.

Comment: Helpful answer.. :)

Comment: at Dash Hud / "details" / default applications / photos

Comment: from the Shotwell menu: Photo -> Tools -> Crop

Comment: First I have to "open" the picture, only after that the Photo menu appears.

Answer (score 20):

The default viewer is very limited, no editing and it doesn't support animated GIFs. What I recommend is installing gthumb which is in the Ubuntu repositories. Gthumb is fast loading and provides all the basic editing functions without the complication of GIMP. It also serves as a image manager which doesn't impose a date based folder structure for images. I for one prefer filing by event or subject -- makes images much easier to locate.

Comment: Great recommendation!  gthumb is working perfectly for me

Comment: I normally don't give a "me too" kind of comments, but after the frustration of MyPaint not having a simple crop function, I totally endorse the recommendation of gThumb. It's great for a quick editing, and it's fast! Thank you.